# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use associated_class.set() instead

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an error where I tried to patch up but I don't understand where should I change the code.

This is my `serializer.py` file:

```py
class TeacherSignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = UserCreateSerializer()
# teacher = SchoolSerializer(read_only=True)
# teachers = ClassSerializer(read_only=True)
# teach = SubjectSerializer(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Teacher
    fields = (
        'name',
        'email',
        'mobile_number',
        'city',
        'school_name',
        'subject',
        'user',
        'associated_class',
    )
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
    teacher = Teacher.objects.create(**validated_data)
    teacher.set_user(user)
    return teacher
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
class TeacherSigupAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = TeacherSignupSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        teacher = serializer.save()
        if teacher:
            return Response({
                "status": True,
                "teacher": TeacherSerializer(teacher, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            })

    return Response({
        "status": False,
        "message": "Teacher is already exists"
    }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The error I got was `(place_error_here)` but when I changed my code, that also gave the same issue.